# How to display a template for empty tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, partial-views

I have the following model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collabos
  has_many :files
end
```

I want to display a conditional partial so the `current_user` can create a collabo or a file, when these models are empty?

Here's my first attempt, but it doesn't work well.

```
<% if current_user.files.empty? || current_user.collabos.empty? %>
  <%= "create a file/collabo" %>
<% else %>
   <%= yield %>
<% end %>
```

What's the best way to go for this kind of issue?

I think the picture below is better to show you the kind of behaviour I want to implement [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **and** instead of **or** :

```
<% if current_user.files.empty? and current_user.collabos.empty? %>
```

However, it is always a nice idea to create User instance methods like :

```
def has_files?
  files.empty? ? false : true
end
```

so that it becomes :

```
<% if current_user.has_files? and current_user.has_collabos? %>
```

(and you can always create a has_files_and_collabos method as well, if it's reusable code)

Comment: Except please don't do stuff like `boolean? ? true : false` :). Just write the method as the inverse in this case: `def has_files?; !files.empty?; end`

Comment: well, that's a matter of taste, i prefer a ternary in such cases :) One can always use exists?, if they want a simpler, easier to read version.

Comment: I would recommend using `&&` instead of `and` in Ruby since they have different precedence, and the behavior of `&&` is probably the way of least surprise. E.g. `x = "one" and "two"` and `x = "one" && "two"` set `x` to different values. In the case of your code, they would do the same thing, but it could bite you if you use it elsewhere.

Comment: @HenrikN This is only a problem if there is a '=' because = has higher precedence than 'and'. If you use it to set a value, you are right, you should use &&. But in an if, 'and' is better because it is easier to read :)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys? But I want to know if there's a better way to keep it DRY, just like in the picture I posted on the question.

Comment: @blawzoo The picture you posted is just an active_admin basic screen. It's not about DRY, DRY represents non repetitive code, and has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: I know that it's active admin, but the point is how to implement a view that suggest to create instances for every single empty model.

Comment: I don't understand what you say :/ Maybe you need to open up a new question and better describe your problem.